# c++のif else文について

Tags: c++

```
int w = 98;
int x = 99;
int y = 0;
int z = 1;

if(x >= 99)
{
    if(x < 99)
        cout << y << endl;
    else
        cout << z << endl;
}
else
{
    if(x == 99)
        cout << x << endl;
    else
        cout << w << endl;
}
```

上記コードのアウトプットは99と表示されると考えておりましたが、実際には1と表示されます。
理由につき、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x = 99は99以上　かつ 99未満"ではない"ため
z = 1が表示されています

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。以上の表記を見逃しておりました。